# Laravel and ChartJS - Trying to get count of array

Tags: mysql, laravel, group-by, eloquent

I am trying to create a chart from my MySQL db for use in Laravel.

To test the chart, I put in an array like [1, 2, 3, 4, 5] and it works perfectly. But when I try to grab data from my db, it doesn't work. I have a db with the following fields:

```
id  
project  
stage  
status  
timestamps
```

What I am trying to show in my chart are the number of projects in each stage.  So the stages are:

```
Waiting to Start  
In Progress  
Waiting for Information  
Pre-Launch  
Launched
```

My query is the following:

```
$total = Project::all()->groupBy('stage')->count('stage');
```

That does not work. I've tried a couple other queries but not sure how to get the number of projects in each stage and output that to an array. Also, would like to get the data in the particular order which is not alphabetical or anything so cannot use orderBy, etc.

Thank you for your help.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

So after much trial and error, I decided to put my JS code in the blade file directly rather than bringing it through externally.

When I did this,

```
data: {{ $t }}
```

works perfectly.

I am not sure why it works when directly in the blade file but not when I include it. I made sure it loads after jQuery so still don't know why.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

Try it that way:

```
$total = Project::groupBy('stage')->get();
```

Then loop through each stage, and get the `count()`.

Comment: I guess that's where I'm having trouble. How would I loop through and get the count? foreach ($total as $t) { $t->count(); } does not work.

Comment: It doesn't provide me with the count for each stage.  Just says 1.